# How to use custom configuration file in combination with autostart script in Openbox?

Tags: linux, bash, lxde, openbox

I'm trying to use Openbox with an autostart script as well as a separate copy of "rc.xml" (this is to be able to have multiple configurations on the same computer, but that's not relevant). Let's say this file is called "custom-rc.xml". How do I make Openbox use that one instead of "rc.xml"? By doing some browsing through my filesystem I found that the script "openbox-session" contained this code:

```
exec /usr/bin/openbox --startup "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openbox-autostart OPENBOX" "$@"
```

The above code launches openbox and makes it run a script that will run autostart.
I also found the script "openbox-lxde" (I have lxde installed), and it contained this:

```
exec openbox --config-file $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/openbox/lxde-rc.xml $@
```

Is there a way to combine these operations when running openbox? This would allow me to make a script that launches openbox with aan autostart script and my own configuration file.

Comment: I've been looking for something similar, so that you can start openbox sessions with a concrete configuration file, replacing the previous one, but it seems that `--config-file` cannot be combined with others like `--reconfigure` or `--restart`. If you find a way, please report here, there seems to be very little documentation about this.

Comment: Actually, `--config-file` and `--replace` can be combined, although the result doesn't seem to be precisely what we expect. So `openbox --config-file .config/openbox/myfile.xml --replace` does reload openbox with a different configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

You may do this:
in "openbox-session" script in exec line after `openbox` add `--config-file FILE`
 change FILE to the way to your "custom-rc.xml"

Answer (score 0):

Combine `--config-file` and `--replace` like this:

```
openbox --config-file pathto/myfile.xml --replace &
```

which does reload openbox with a different configuration file, even if some weird messages might appear, like:

```
Openbox-Message: Requested key "XF86Terminal" does not exist on the display
Openbox-Message: Invalid action "PgUp" requested. No such action exists.
Openbox-Message: Requested key "XF86Terminal" does not exist on the display
```

while openbox was perfectly fine with these keys and actions in the original configuration file (in a Lubuntu 16.04).